# Short story about reincarnation and god

Tags: story-identification, short-stories, reincarnation

I'm looking for a short story (similar to Harlan Ellison, maybe even by him). When people die, their souls go into this universal god/spirit/whatever, and when a new person (or alien) is born, a bit of this spirit cloud goes into the baby. People have to learn lessons/experience what happened in their past lives.

Probably 1990s or earlier.

Could have been in Omni, or some collection of short stories.

Comment: This is awfully vague. Are there no specific details you can remember?

Comment: Yes, sorry, it was about 20 or 30 years ago! Since then I remembered that it was more like a crime novel (although of course, given the subject matter, was also science fiction). However, I *think* that it was actually a book called Death Knell by C Terry Kline (I downloaded it for Kindle yesterday, and will read it and update whether it was the correct story)